# Can not set text for Label

Tags: objective-c, label, protocols

In controller I have label property:

```
@interface BallsViewController : UIViewController <UIInteraction>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ScoreLabel;

-(void)UpdateScore:(int)score;
@end

@interface BallsViewController ()
@end

@implementation BallsViewController
@synthesize ScoreLabel;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)UpdateScore:(int)score
{
    NSString *scoreStr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
    [self.ScoreLabel setText:scoreStr];
    [self.InfoLabel setText:scoreStr];

}

@end
```

UpdateScore is protocol method. When I want to set text to ScoreLabel it have value : ScoreLabel    UILabel *   0x00000000

It means that it is not initialize?

When I set text, on ui it not change.

Comment: On your Nib or Storyboard view have you connected the label to your ScoreLabel? Also are you certain that UpdateScore is being called?

Comment: Yes, I connect it. UpdateScore always is invoke.

Comment: What do you get if you `NSLog(@"%@", self.ScoreLabel);` in your `UpdateScore:` method

Comment: Is UpdateScore being called on the main thread?

Comment: And if you connected in interface builder, where is the initWithNib function?

Comment: @Paul.s I get null. What it means ?

Comment: I resolve problem from other response : BallsViewController* controller = [[BallsViewController alloc] init];
    controller.ScoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20)];
    [self addSubview: controller.ScoreLabel]; But someone can explain me why controller and controls are not initialized itself ? Why I must init it ?

Comment: Have you set you class to BallsViewController from UIViewController in the inspector for your storyboard or NIB?

Comment: I am beginner and I have problem with what You saying... :/ How can I set in storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your Label as Strong.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ScoreLabel;
```